Why is the polyfill (core-js) for Array.prototype.push so much slower than the native push,
for example, pushing 1 million data points takes the polyfill over 8 seconds longer than the native version?
It's important. I said it three times.
I have tested different versions of core-js, and the issue remains the same.
I have tested different versions of core-js, and the issue remains the same.
I have tested different versions of core-js, and the issue remains the same.
